# File reader deletes the contet of a file

Tags: java

I'm writing a java server and always read requests form the browser. For example, I have in browser `http://localhost:8080/C:\Users\1\Desktop\tur.txt` and read this request. Then saves a file path. Then I want to print the contents of the file to browser. For example, some text which is in `tur.txt`.

I'm doing it with a method in another class.

Here is a code of this class:

```
public class FileReader {
    BufferedReader in;
    File DataFile;


    public void Reader(String directory, PrintStream out) throws IOException {
        try {

            File stockInputFile = new File(directory);
            File StockOutputFile = new File(directory);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(stockInputFile);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(StockOutputFile);
            int count;
            if (new File(directory).isDirectory()) {
                directory=directory.replace('\\', '/');
                out.print("HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently\r\n"+
                        "Location: /"+directory+"/\r\n\r\n");
                out.close();
                return;
            }

            // Open the file (may throw FileNotFoundException)
            InputStream f=new FileInputStream(directory);

            // Determine the MIME type and print HTTP header
            String mimeType="text/plain";
            if (directory.endsWith(".html") || directory.endsWith(".htm"))
                mimeType="text/html";
            else if (directory.endsWith(".jpg") || directory.endsWith(".jpeg"))
                mimeType="image/jpeg";
            else if (directory.endsWith(".gif"))
                mimeType="image/gif";
            else if (directory.endsWith(".txt"))
                mimeType="text/txt";
            else if (directory.endsWith(".class"))
                mimeType="application/octet-stream";
            out.print("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"+
                    "Content-type: "+mimeType+"\r\n\r\n");
            System.out.println(mimeType);
            // Send file contents to client, then close the connection
            byte[] a=new byte[4096];
            int n;
            while ((n=f.read(a))>0)
             out.write(a, 0, n);
       //     out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
            out.println("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n"+
                    "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"+
                    "<html><head></head><body>"+directory+" not found</body></html>\n");
            out.close();
        }
    }
    }
```

It takes a directory to find a file a file on disk and PrintStream (`PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(serSock.getOutputStream()));`) to print the content to browser. But, the problem is that when I read this file. The content of this file removes. That means all that text that I had in `tur.txt` deletes. And the file becomes emtpty intead of beeng printed to the browser.

Can anyone explain why? Thank you.

Comment: You're opening a FileOutputStrean pointing to the file you want to read. This will clear the file contents as the output stream by default overwrites the file contents.

Comment: Just a side note: Java 7 has Files.probeContentType(path) to get the mime type.

Comment: Oh yes! Thank you @Iamsomeone ! I'm so blind.

Comment: @Lemmy Should I make my comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(stockInputFile);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(StockOutputFile);
```

In FileOutputSteam. So when I deleted these 2 lines the program started to work correctly. I forgot that FileOutputStream clears all the data stored in the file.

I would like to thank @lamsomeone for his help.